# How to do Java tcp client <-> Qt tcp server socket communication

Tags: java, android, qt, sockets, tcp

What I want to know is if this is a good way to do this, or if there's another better and optimal one. (This is for a local network only, not Internet)

I'm trying to implement a communication system between a tcp **server** (written in **Qt** in windows) and a tcp **client** (written in **java** in android) using sockets. This is

I need to basically do two things: transfer files, and transfer some data.

- So, I've decided to use a string based communication method to handle
  the custom protocol.
- For the data transfer, I've tought to create a xml file with the data
  (convert the collections to xml markers and set its values), send the
  file, and then parse it in the other point.

I have not much knowledge in network programming so please give me a hand on this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made 2 simple client applications using the socket communication for my exams. They both communicate with a Java server, one of them is an android application, the second one is a Qt application (this one should help you as you want to know how to make your Java app communicate with Qt). You can download these 3 applications [here](https://bitbucket.org/Ekami/resavionapp_pti/overview).
Excuse me if some comments have been made in French, I use to code in English but I'm facing a French jury :P. 
Take a deep look to NetworkUtil::receiveString(QDataStream &in) method in the Qt application.
Also always use qint32 to receive int from the Java application.
If you need further explanations please let me know.
E-Kami

Comment: finally i've move the server side to java.

Comment: @E-Kami, i'm also trying to do the same but i'm stuck since a while, i've tried to download your files but they are not available anymore. can you please update the link or send them to me: puissancisma@gmail.com

Comment: @Xsmael I updated the link to the bitbucket repository. I don't know if this code is still compiling on the new version of QT (for the java part it works for sure) as I created this project when I was still a 1st-2nd year student. `ResAvion_Client_App` is the QT app and `ResAvion_Server_App` the java server app.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but they said: "You do not have access to this repository."  :(

Comment: Sorry for that, you should have access now